# Finding the handle to a WPF window

Tags: wpf, window, handle

Windows forms had a property win1.Handle which, if I recall, returns the handle of the main window handle?

Is there an equivalent way to get the handle of a WPF Window?

I found the following code online,

```
IntPtr windowHandle = 
    new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
```

But I don't think that will help me because my application has multiple windows.

Comment: Let me give you some friendly advice, Evan. Don't do cargo cult programming! Dissect the code you found online. You can see clearly that it passes Application.Current.MainWindow, and from that you can reason that by passing it a reference to a different window, you'll get your answer. I've never used WindowInteropHelper, but was still able to answer the question simply be reasoning it out.

Comment: you're right, thanks! i'm tired today :).

Comment: No problem! And I didn't mean it as criticism, just to be helpful. We've all done a little cargo-culting now and then. :)

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Well, instead of passing `Application.Current.MainWindow`, just pass a reference to whichever window it is you want: `new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle` and so on.

Comment: I just discovered that the FileSave common dialog takes a reference to a top-level window, so you can pass, for example, a reference to the MainWindow of the application. Save Interop services for when you really need it.

Answer (score 52):

Just use your window with the WindowsInteropHelper class:

```
// ... Window myWindow = get your Window instance...
IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).Handle;
```

Right now, you're asking for the Application's main window, of which there will always be one.  You can use this same technique on any Window, however, provided it is a System.Windows.Window derived Window class.

Comment: Thanks Reed Copsey. For VB.Net in case somebody need it, it is : Dim windowHandle As IntPtr = New Interop.WindowInteropHelper(Me).Handle

Answer (score 17):

you can use :

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
```

Comment: This won't work with WPF windows, it always returns a null handle.

Answer (score 4):

In my use case I needed a handle to the main window during startup, and no matter what I did I couldn't get `new WindowInteropHelper(...).Handle` to return anything other than a null handle since the window hadn't been initialized yet.

You can use the [`EnsureHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.ensurehandle?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method instead, which will create the handle if it doesn't already exist, or return the current one if it does exist.

```cs
var hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).EnsureHandle();
```

Once the application has started, it continues using the same handle without issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want window handles for ALL of your application's `Window`s for some reason, you can use the `Application.Windows` property to get at all the Windows and then use `WindowInteropHandler` to get at their handles as you have already demonstrated.

Comment: The thing that may be missing here is getting the Handle to a CONTROL (System.Windows.Controls.Control rather than a System.Windows.Window)

Answer (score 0):

Works after OnLoaded() event in my case. In the constructor it gives a zero handle.

```
var winHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
```