# Forcing the creation of a WPF Window's native Win32 handle

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winapi, handle

I need to access the Win32 window handles of some of my WPF windows so I can handle Win32 activation messages.  I know I can use `PresentationSource.FromVisual` or `WindowInteropHelper` to get the Win32 window handle, but I am running into problems if the WPF window has not been created yet.

If I use `PresentationSource.FromVisual` and the window has not been created, the returned `PresentationSource` is null.  If I use `WindowInteropHelper` and the window has not been created, the `Handle` property is `IntPtr.Zero` (null).

I tried calling `this.Show()` and `this.Hide()` on the window before I tried to access the handle.  I can then get the handle, but the window flashes momentarily on the screen (ugly!).

Does anyone know of a way to force a WPF window to be created?  In Windows Forms this was as easy as accessing the `Form.Handle` property.

**Edit:** I ended up going with a variant on Chris Taylor's answer.  Here it is, in case it helps someone else:

```
static void InitializeWindow(Window window)
{
    // Get the current values of the properties we are going to change
    double oldWidth = window.Width;
    double oldHeight = window.Height;
    WindowStyle oldWindowStyle = window.WindowStyle;
    bool oldShowInTaskbar = window.ShowInTaskbar;
    bool oldShowActivated = window.ShowActivated;

    // Change the properties to make the window invisible
    window.Width = 0;
    window.Height = 0;
    window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    window.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    window.ShowActivated = false;

    // Make WPF create the window's handle
    window.Show();
    window.Hide();

    // Restore the old values
    window.Width = oldWidth;
    window.Height = oldHeight;
    window.WindowStyle = oldWindowStyle;
    window.ShowInTaskbar = oldShowInTaskbar;
    window.ShowActivated = oldShowActivated;
}

// Use it like this:
InitializeWindow(myWpfWindow);
```

Comment: Have you seen this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556182/finding-the-handle-to-a-wpf-window - it might not help as it doesn't mention whether the window already exists or not.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks! Yes, I have seen that. Unfortunately, it has the problem with the window not being created yet.

Comment: I thought I'd mention it to get your reply so that if your case was different it wouldn't get selected as a duplicate.

Comment: Do you actually need to trigger handle creation early?  or do you just need to manipulate the handle before its shown? IIRC, you could use the SourceInitialized event for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to set window state to minimized and not to show in the taskbar before Showing the window. Try something like this.

```
  IntPtr hWnd;
  WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wnd);

  WindowState prevState = wnd.WindowState;
  bool prevShowInTaskBar = wnd.ShowInTaskbar;

  wnd.ShowInTaskbar = false;
  wnd.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
  wnd.Show();
  hWnd = helper.Handle;
  wnd.Hide();

  wnd.ShowInTaskbar = prevShowInTaskBar;
  wnd.WindowState = prevState;
```

Comment: Thanks!  I ended up going with a variant of this (see my edit on the question).

Comment: [@DanielAlbuschat's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4826741/24874) is simpler and avoids flickering.

Comment: Yes, the answer below is far cleaner.

Comment: Newer answers are better as the framework evolved to support these scenarios better.

Answer (score 24):

Use [`WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.ensurehandle(v=vs.110).aspx), it does exactly what you need.

Comment: I got the same problem, and this one is the best answer!

Comment: Again, this is a far better answer than the accepted one! Please use this instead, everybody!

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a solution if the WindowInteropHelper's handle is NULL. Hopefully this post gives some additional information how to solve it.

One solution is to use:

```
var window = new Window();
var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).EnsureHandle()
```

This works only with .NET Framework 4.

At the moment I am using .NET Framework 3.5 so I needed another solution. Then I found a forum thread with a WindowInteropHelper extension method:

```
#region

using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

#endregion

namespace System.Windows.Interop
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   Provides NetFX 4.0 EnsureHandle method for
    ///   NetFX 3.5 WindowInteropHelper class.
    /// </summary>
    public static class WindowInteropHelperExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///   Creates the HWND of the window if the HWND has not been created yet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name = "helper">An instance of WindowInteropHelper class.</param>
        /// <returns>An IntPtr that represents the HWND.</returns>
        /// <remarks>
        ///   Use the EnsureHandle method when you want to separate
        ///   window handle (HWND) creation from the
        ///   actual showing of the managed Window.
        /// </remarks>
        public static IntPtr EnsureHandle(this WindowInteropHelper helper)
        {
            if (helper == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("helper");

            if (helper.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var window = (Window) typeof (WindowInteropHelper).InvokeMember(
                    "_window",
                    BindingFlags.GetField |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, helper, null);

                typeof (Window).InvokeMember(
                    "SafeCreateWindow",
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, window, null);
            }

            return helper.Handle;
        }
    }
}
```

The WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle() does not expect a window is already created.

> Reference: Alexander Yudakov - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/wpf/thread/5f89ac58-d2ef-4ac0-aefb-b2826dbef48a

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck on this same issue and went with [J Pollack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036911/1270267) (because it seems cleaner to me), but needed something that would run both on the .NET runtime 2.0 and 4.0.

But when I did that I ended up with an ugly [MissingMethodException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmethodexception(v=vs.110).aspx) because **SafeCreateWindow** does not exist in the .NET runtime 4.0 anymore. To make the code work on both runtimes I decided to catch the MissingMethodException and invoke the equivalent in the .NET 4.0 runtime instead like this:

```cs
    public static IntPtr EnsureHandle(this WindowInteropHelper helper)
    {
        if (helper == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("helper");

        if (helper.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var window = (Window)typeof(WindowInteropHelper).InvokeMember(
                "_window",
                BindingFlags.GetField |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                null, helper, null);

            try
            {
                // SafeCreateWindow only exists in the .NET 2.0 runtime. If we try to
                // invoke this method on the .NET 4.0 runtime it will result in a
                // MissingMethodException, see below.
                typeof(Window).InvokeMember(
                    "SafeCreateWindow",
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, window, null);
            }
            catch (MissingMethodException)
            {
                // If we ended up here it means we are running on the .NET 4.0 runtime,
                // where the method we need to call for the handle was renamed/replaced
                // with CreateSourceWindow.
                typeof(Window).InvokeMember(
                    "CreateSourceWindow",
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                    BindingFlags.Instance |
                    BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, window, new object[] { false });
            }
        }

        return helper.Handle;
    }
```

This allowed me to compile the code with .NET 3.5 but run it on .NET runtime 4.0 on systems that only have the higher runtime version installed (namely Windows 8 and above).