# How can I put the monitor to sleep when using C#/WPF (Not WinForms!)

Tags: c#, wpf

The trouble I'm having is with using...

```
[DllImport("user32")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

...and then...

```
SendMessage(???, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)MONITOR_OFF);
```

SendMessage wants the Form's Handle but I'm not using Forms so cannot get the Handle.

Is there any other way I can put the monitor to sleep OR get the Handle in WPF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the handle to a WPF window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556182/finding-the-handle-to-a-wpf-window)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the Handle for a WPF Window use:

```
  new WindowInteropHelper(YourWPFWindow).Handle
```

[MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Write [`new WindowInteropHelper(someWindow).Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Or use

```
HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(this);
source.Handle...
```

to get a handle from a single element in the form, also runs for the whole window.